# ping hostname resolves to wrong ip

Tags: networking, command-line, ping, cache

If I ping a server by the hostname from the command prompt, I get the wrong IP address. The IP address returned used to be the IP, but not anymore. How do I flush the cache? It is not the "ipconfig /flushdns" cache or the [arp cache](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tips-flush-the-arp-cache-in-windows-7/), "netsh interface ip delete arpcache", but rather I presume the netbios cache or something.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping jmr-hv1

Pinging jmr-hv1.ad.jmr.com [192.168.20.76] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.20.86: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.20.86: Destination host unreachable.
```

Whereas performing the following results in (order does not matter):

```
Pinging JMR-HV1 [192.168.20.14] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.20.14: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.20.14: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.20.14: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.20.14: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.20.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

There is a cache, which I need to clear. Which one is it?

Comment: "Two, I am trying to resolve a server name on our network, not a web address" still uses dns

Comment: Check your `hosts` file, there might be an old entry for that name.

Comment: @Aganju Nope, just checked. I saw an article mentioning that. I should have mentioned that in my question. There is only one entry. I have not modified my hosts file, as there is no need. That was a nice thought, though.